# Как убрать звуки щелчков перехода в TWebBrowser?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, borland

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как убрать в `TWebBrowser` звуки щелчков перехода со страницы на страницу?

Answer (score 1):

Обратите внимание на процедуру `CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled` в URLMON.DLL.
Она позволяет устанавливать некоторые Feature Controls на лету.

Прочитать о ней можно здесь: [CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled function (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537168(v=vs.85).aspx)
Список Feature Controls можно найти здесь: [Introduction to Feature Controls (Windows)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537184(VS.85).aspx)

Из этого списка вас интересует опция `FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS`.
Включение этой опции для приложения позволит добиться желаемого эффекта.

> Quiet Navigation (FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS) - This control
>   disables the sound that is produced when clicking on links.

Выглядеть это будет как-то так:

```
HRESULT hr = CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, TRUE);
```

Полный пример кода:

```
unit untUrlMon;

implementation

uses
  Windows;

function CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FeatureEntry: DWORD; dwFlags: DWORD; fEnable: BOOL): HRESULT; stdcall; external 'urlmon.dll';

initialization
  CoInternetSetFeatureEnabled(FEATURE_DISABLE_NAVIGATION_SOUNDS, SET_FEATURE_ON_PROCESS, True); 

end.
```

Составлено на основе следующих ответов на StackOveflow:

- [Annoying click sound in TWebbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/613943/annoying-click-sound-in-twebbrowser)
- [Clicking sound in TWebbrowser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5892072/clicking-sound-in-twebbrowser)

Answer (score 0):

http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=2838#post_750188

Comment: Уверен, автор был бы признателен за ваше экспертное мнение в дополнение к ссылке.